# Is there a VSCode plugin or IDE that can display the dependency of TypeScript functions or call stack view?

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, ide, webstorm

Is there a VSCode plugin or IDE that can display the dependency of TypeScript functions or call stack view?

I want to display a view that can show the call stack view of TypeScript function?

eg:

```js
function foo() {
  const something = a();

  const anotherThing = b();
  
  return c(something + anotherThing)
}
function a() { return a1() }
function a1() { return a2() }
function a2() { // do something }
function b() { return b1() }
function c() { return c1() }
```

then  I can see a view like that:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In WebStorm, there is **Navigate > Call Hierarchy** view that shows a call tree:

[image]

There is no way to represent it as a diagram though;  the only available diagram for TypeScript is a module dependency diagram that shows how the modules depend on each other (based on `require()` and `import` statements).